# How do I quit a game while streaming to the Steam Link?

Tags: steam-link, steam-in-home-streaming

I have a Steam Link and I’m streaming a game from a computer across the house. I can’t figure out how to quit the game and return to my library (or the “big picture” view or whatever).

I’m using a controller, obviously, so control schemes are sometimes wonky.

Comment: The same way you would quit the game without Steam Link. What exactly is your problem (which game?) and what have you tried?

Comment: I pressed every button on the controller in every combination. Apparently, the first game I chose had bad controller support and somehow, even the big center orb button, which I now know brings up the Steam menu, didn’t work?! I had to kill the app from the PC. I tried another game and the center button did the trick. Maybe a better question is how to kill misbehaving apps?

Comment: Yeah, there are some games or apps that have messed up controller configurations. Sometimes this also seems to be a bug and only happens sometimes. You might be able to re-enable the big center button by turning the controller off (hold it for 5 secs) and on again. Btw: You can still improve your question by telling us the actual name of the problematic game/app.